# Strange Behavior with RegionPlot

Tags: plotting, evaluation

Consider the following code.

```
RegionPlot[Print[{x, y}], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotPoints -> 2]
```

> ```
> {-1.996,-1.996}
> {Region`Private`RegionVar[1],Region`Private`RegionVar[2]}
> {-2.,-2.}
> {2.,-2.}
> {-2.,2.}
> {2.,2.}
> ```

My question is: what is `RegionPlot` doing to create the first two lines of output? I do not understand why the first sample point is `{-1.996, -1.996}` and why the second sample point is `` {Region`Private`RegionVar[1],Region`Private`RegionVar[2]} ``.

I am running this in *Mathematica* 9. I do not recall this happening in an earlier version.

**Edit:** I changed the code above to give a better minimal working example. I leave below the code I first gave along with its truncated output.

```
myFunc[pt_] := Module[ {bool},
  bool = Sin[ pt[[1]] ] > 0;
  Print[pt, bool];
  If[ bool, Return[True], Return[False] ];
];

RegionPlot[myFunc[ {x, y} ], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotPoints -> 2]
```

> ```
> {-1.996,-1.996}False
>
> {Region`Private`RegionVar[1],Region`Private`RegionVar[2]}Sin[Region`Private`RegionVar[1]]>0
>
> {-2.,-2.}False
>
> {2.,-2.}True
> ```

Comment: I can confirm that this doesn't happen in version 8.0.4.0 but in version 9.0.0.0 - no idea what changed...

Comment: As a clue this resembles the behavior of regular Plot[] which first evaluates the function with a numeric argument, then a symbolic arg, followed by the remaining numeric values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to a representative at Wolfram Research

> This behavior doesn't appear to be documented, but also doesn't appear to
>   be a bug of any kind. I apologize, we have no information about this aspect
>   of the internal workings of RegionPlot.

Answer (score 1):

This still happens in Mathematica 10.4, and `RegionPlot` can fail to produce a plot, with the message `Throw::nocatch: "Uncaught Throw[$Failed] returned to top level."`.

As a temporary fix one can use `NumericQ` to evaluate the predicate function only when `RegionPlot` sends genuine numeric data:

```
myFunc[pt_] := Module[{bool},
    If[! NumericQ[pt[[1]]], Return[False]];    <-----
    bool = Sin[pt[[1]]] > 0;
    Print[pt,bool];
    If[bool, Return[True], Return[False]];
];
```

This is not ideal, as the evaluation result can be incorrect in one point (corresponding to the second call of the predicate function by `RegionPlot`) but at least `RegionPlot` will output a graph and it worked for me.