# Speed up RegionPlot

Tags: plotting, performance-tuning, regions

I want to plot a system of equalities and inequalities. I used a combination of ImplicitRegion and RegionPlot (since RegionPlot cannot plot lines or points). But this method is very slow than using only the RegionPlot. Can this be improved?

Or is there any other alternate to plot a system of equalities and inequalities?

```
RegionPlot[x^2 + y^3 < 2 && x + y < 1, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]; // AbsoluteTiming

(*{0.146477,Null}*)

RegionPlot[x^2 + y^3 < 2 && x + y == 1, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]; // AbsoluteTiming

(*{0.0746052,Null}*)

reg1 := ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^3 < 2 && x + y < 1, {x, y}]
reg2 := ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^3 < 2 && x + y == 1, {x, y}]

RegionPlot[reg1]; // AbsoluteTiming

(*{0.875837,Null}*)

RegionPlot[reg2]; // AbsoluteTiming

(*{0.405988,Null}*)
```

(I dont always know the solution range)

**UPDATE**
I learnt from the comments that one of the reason for `RegionPlot[ImplicitRegion[]]` to be slower compared to `RegionPlot` is the necessity to find the region bounds in the former. So I tried to find the bounds using `RegionBounds` and apply in `RegionPlot`. However this combo is slower compared to using `RegionPlot` directly on the `ImplicitRegion`

Also, the third case in the example code I posted may work faster in many of your machines (then I believe the first case with only RegionPlot will be much faster in you machine). My question is a general way to speed up the working of `RegionPlot[ImplicitRegion[]]` when compared to `RegionPlot`. If that is impossible, I want to know if there is any other way to plot this? (For example, depending on the `RegionDimension`, choose `RegionPlot` or `ContorPlot`. Though this approach also involves the knowledge of the bounds)

Comment: They do different things, which you can observe by comparing `DiscretizeGraphics@RegionPlot[<inequality>]` with the output of `RegionPlot[reg1]` etc.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I want to plot system of equalities and inequalities faster. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Do you mean like the first two examples, or you want something faster?

Comment: @MichaelE2 I need the third example to work faster like the first one (the second example does not work. So dont consider its timing)

Comment: `RegionPlot[RegionMember[reg1, {x, y}], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]`?  You save time by (I think) not computing the boundary. Note the difference in output though. I'm not sure if that's what you want. If you want the boundary computed automatically, it's going to take extra time to do it -- I don't think there's a way around it.

Comment: @MichaelE2 but your logic will not work for reg2

Comment: Did you not say "the third example"??

Comment: @MichaelE2 I need a general method to plot cases like first and second. So I used the ImplicitRegion function to do that (example third and fourth). However, that method is slow. So I want either a different method or tweaks in this method to make plotting faster. I know the system of equations and inequalities. So I dont need to use RegionMember[]. This reduces to the same case as first and second example, where the second example is not plotted

Comment: Maybe it's version-dependent: http://i.stack.imgur.com/aGrp1.png (V10.4)

Comment: @MichaelE2 I'm using MMA 10.2. Can you check how the first example fare in your system?

Comment: It's slower, though not as slow as your timing: http://i.stack.imgur.com/uEpJH.png

Comment: @garej I am looking for general way to plot it. In your solution, I dont know the logic to automatically set the PlotRange and PlotPoints. Further, my region can be of any geometry (circle, disk,etc). If you could show a generic code with region equations as input, it will be clearer for me to understand

Comment: @garej My need is to show the result obtained from Reduce graphically. I understand the part between no solution and not working. My doubt is how to extend your logic to work for any result obtained from Reduce. Also, x+y==a will not always be in my result.

Comment: @Prashanth, so, do like that `ImplicitRegion[Reduce[x^2 + y^3 < 2 && x + y == 1, {x, y}], {x, y}] // RegionPlot // AbsoluteTiming`

Comment: @garej That is what I have done in the third and fourth cases of my example code (the thing inside ImplicitRegion is the result of Reduce). But it is somewhat slow and I wanted to know if there is any other faster way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not completely sure what you are looking for, but this option seems fast enough:

```
With[{a = 1}, 
  RegionPlot[{x^2 + y^3 < 2, x^2 + y^3 < 2 && x + y == a}, 
   {x, -2, 2}, {y, -(-2 - a), -(2 - a)}, 
   BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Thickness[0.02]]]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

**Edit 2**
 Following @JasonB comments we may add `PlotRange` without `Show`, so plotting range and domains are different now. Therefore if you do not know where the solution is you may set `xmin` and `xmax` as large as you wish and adjust the range accordingly (note that sometimes one has to correct option `PlotPoints` to make the line `x + y = a` visible).

```
With[{a = 1, xmin = -3, xmax = 5, range = 4}, 
 RegionPlot[{x^2 + y^3 < 2, x^2 + y^3 < 2 && x + y == a}, 
 {x, xmin, xmax}, {y, -(xmin - a), -(xmax - a)}, PlotPoints -> 10, 
  PlotRange -> {{-range, range}, {-range, range}}]]
```

[image]

Comment: This is really weird, I'd even call it a minor bug.  You don't need the `With` to get the plot to work, but it will only work with the right plot range.  Just check out this:  `{RegionPlot[{x^2 + y^3 < 2 && x + y == 1}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 3}], 
 RegionPlot[{x^2 + y^3 < 2 && x + y == 1}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}],
 RegionPlot[{x^2 + y^3 < 2 && x + y == 1}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -1, 3}]}`

Comment: @JasonB, you will be surprised but I'm aware of this and made `a` just for conveniece - i.e. if one wants to change equality to, say, `x + y == 2` or smth. I also do not think that it is a bug. It is just internal logic of RegionPlot, whatever strange.

Comment: And I would absolutely still call that strange internal logic of `RegionPlot` buggy.  I would expect `RegionPlot` to work for all 3 of the plot ranges I wrote above, and the fact that it doesn't means that `RegionPlot` is doing something wrong.  Nowhere in the documentation does it state that if you want to plot a one-dimensional region, you are restricted to a certain range around that region.

Comment: Moreover, what if the user **wants** to make a region plot that shows both of these regions, like your first plot above, with a plot range of `{{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}`?   The workaround here won't allow that.    They would need to make two plots and combine them with `Show`, like `Show[
 RegionPlot[x^2 + y^3 < 2 && x + y < 1, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}],
 RegionPlot[{x^2 + y^3 < 2 && x + y == 1}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -1, 3}, 
  BoundaryStyle -> Red]
 ]`

Comment: @JasonB, what are you fighting for? :-)) `RgionPlot` is strange per se. Did you see that [post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19276/strange-behavior-with-regionplot)?

Comment: I'm not fighting, just nitpicking  :-P I just think it's important to find the flaws in the code so they can fix them.  And this is a flaw.

Comment: @JasonB, by the way, I do not have such problems with speed with the OP, so I think the problem itself is a bit artificial. We could make just: `reg1 := ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^3 < 2, {x, y}]; reg2 := 
 ImplicitRegion[x + y == 1, {x, y}]; RegionPlot[{reg1, reg2}]`

Comment: Agreed, if you add `, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}` to that, it would seem to give what OP wants, and only takes 0.15 seconds on my machine.  I [really like](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:9490+[regions]) the region functionality, and I know it's new, so it has room for improvement.